# Building SQL3 db error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

I am building a database of skills and in the beginning thinking that I would need a title param for them I added it as a required param.  I would like to get rid of the title param all together so that I can just create new skills and a description.  Right now there is an error because it is also looking for a :title.  Here is my controller:

```
class SkillsController < ApplicationController



  def index
    @skills = Skill.all
   end

   def show
    @skills = Skill.all
   end

   def new
    @skills = Skill.all

   end

 def create
  @skills = Skill.new(skill_params)
  if @skills.save
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
  else
    @skills = Skill.find(:all)
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end

   def edit
    @skills = Skill.find(params[:id])
    @skills = Skill.find(:all)
   end

   def update
       @skills = Skill.find(params[:id])
      if @skills.update_attributes(params[:skill])
         redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @skills
      else
         @skills = Skill.find(:all)
         render :action => 'edit'
      end
   end

   def delete
    Skill.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
   end

     def show_skills
      @skills = Skill.find(params[:id])
   end
end

private

  def skill_params
    params.require(:skill).permit(:attribute_1, :attribute_2, :attribute_3)
  end
```

and here is my error when I try and submit a new skill:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in SkillsController#create
SQLite3::ConstraintException: skills.title may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "skills" ("created_at") VALUES (?)
```

I think the easiest way to bypass this issue is to make skill.title not required but I am not sure for certain how exactly to fix it.  I will also post my /new form if that helps:

```
<h1>Add new Skill</h1>
<%= form_tag ({action: "create"}) do %>
<p><label for="skill">Skill</label>:
<%= text_field 'skill', 'title' %></p>

<p><label for="skill_description">Description</label><br/>
<%= text_area 'skill', 'description' %></p>
<%= submit_tag "Create" %>
<% end  %>
<%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'index'} %>
```

I tried getting rid of the 'title' line and it made even more problems.  I will keep messing with the code and researching and thank you anyone who knows anything about my issue.  Cheers and thanks again stackers!!!

Comment: Is your `skill_params` method is an example or you really have it like that?

Comment: I have it like that, is that bad?

Comment: You should be having your `attribute names`.It should be `params.require(:skill).permit(:title, :description)`

Comment: That gave me a new error::::::ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in SkillsController#create
unknown attribute: description

Comment: @skills = Skill.new(skill_params)

Comment: fixed that one by updating my skills.rb I am going to close this post as answered, I will upvote and check as answer if you answer again officially Paven.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you created the `title` column originally with a `NOT NULL` constraint, so the database won't allow the record to be created without a title.

If you truly don't need it, then you should drop the column from the database.

Create a migration:

```
bundle exec rails generate migration remove_title_from_skills
```

Edit the migration file created and add:

```
def change
  remove_column :skills, :title
end
```

Run the migration:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Remove all other references to `:title` in your application.

Comment: I will try this and let you know how it worked, thanks a billion I hope all goes well!=D

Comment: All I get is the same error::::::::NoMethodError in SkillsController#create
undefined method `each' for "Dance":String

Comment: @skills = Skill.new(skill_params)

Comment: @ZachyBear Did you remove `<%= text_field 'skill', 'title' %>` from your form? Is the code in the first post still accurate?

Answer (score 0):

Well,then as i said,your `skill_params` should be like this

```
def skill_params

params.require(:skill).permit(:title,:description)

end
```

You should be permitting your `attributes` in the list of `permitted params`.

For more info,you should be looking at **[Strong Parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)**.